# GetTokenId where to use it

Tags: javascript, firebase

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="signin()">Signin</button>
  <button onclick="fb()">Show</button>
</body>

<script>
  var idToken;
  (function () {
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //content is present
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }());

  function signin() {
    var email = "email@em.com";
    var password = "password";
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (fbuser) {
      console.log("Success");
      idToken = fbuser.getIdToken();
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
  }
  function fb() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user); // It shows the Firebase user
        console.log(firebase.auth().user); // It is still undefined
        user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {  // <------ Check this line
          console.log(idToken); // It shows the Firebase token now
        });
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</html>
```

I am getting `undefined` in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function

Can I use it in javascript? I tried all the possible measures but ended up getting only errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is a callback that should be initialized at the start, not at the click of a button:

```html
<script>
  var idToken;
  (function () {
    var firebaseConfig = {
      //content is present
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log(firebase.auth().user); 
        user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {  
          console.log(idToken); // It shows the Firebase token now
        });
      }
    });
  }());

  function signin() {
    var email = "email@em.com";
    var password = "password";
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (fbuser) {
      console.log("Success");
      idToken = fbuser.getIdToken();
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
  }
</script>
```